# memory reference of a object passed to a List java

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
private final Map<String, List<EventMessage>> namedMessageMap = new HashMap<>();

List<EventMessage> messageList = namedMessageMap.get(queueName);
if (messageList == null) {
      messageList = new ArrayList<>();
      namedMessageMap.put(queueName, messageList);
}

// Add the item in queue
messageList.add(message);
```

i have this code now im thinking about a thing, the message List that i pass to the namedMessageMap will contain the message i add at end? how work in this case the java memory allocation? it point to a new object or to the memory reference?

Comment: *List that i pass to the namedMessageMap will contain the message i add at end* >> why don"t you just try and see ?^^

Comment: `new ArrayList<>();` will create new object (memory allocation involved) which reference is stored in `messageList` variable, then you are putting this reference in map (reference is copied). Finally, you are adding message in list instance (object) which is accessed by `messageList` reference. Both `namedMessageMap.get(queueName)` and `messageList` will refer to the same object, thus `namedMessageMap.get(queueName)` will return reference to an updated object.

Comment: In Java, there are only objects. There is no such thing as “memory reference”, that is a term you have just invented to confuse yourself. Behind the scenes, the implementation likely uses memory for the objects, but that is something you should not think about, especially not when it distracts you from understanding such a simple piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

new ArrayList<>(); this always creates new object and messageList  is pointing to whichever is latest list assigned. So it will contain message you add at end.